# Trouble generating multiple ranges of values using connect by

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I know that from a start date and end date you can use `connect by` to select all dates within that range. But I'm having trouble generalizing this to multiple start and end dates. Here is a simplified example (using numbers instead of dates):

```
select
    name,
    min + level
from (
    select 'foo' as name, 0 as min, 5 as max from dual
    union all
    select 'bar' as name, 10 as min, 20 as max from dual
)
connect by nocycle
    (prior name = name) and level <= (max - min);
```

I would expect to get 15 rows, but instead I only get 2. Simplifying the query:

```
select
    name,
    min + level
from (
    select 'foo' as name, 0 as min, 5 as max from dual
)
connect by nocycle
    level <= (max - min);
```

I get five rows, as expected. But the following only returns one:

```
select
    name,
    min + level
from (
    select 'foo' as name, 0 as min, 5 as max from dual
)
connect by nocycle
    (prior name = name) and level <= (max - min);
```

As does, inexplicably, the following:

```
select
    name,
    min + level
from (
    select 'foo' as name, 0 as min, 5 as max from dual
)
connect by nocycle
    (prior name = name or 1=1) and level <= (max - min);
```

What's going on here, and how do I remedy it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remedy: Don't use `connect by nocycle`. To break the cycle, add one more condition with PRIOR, which will force a unique additional (system provided) column in each row. Standard is  `... and prior sys_guid() is not null`

Explanation: rather than reinvent the wheel, https://community.oracle.com/thread/2526535

Rewriting the first query:

```
select
    name,
    min + level
from (
    select 'foo' as name, 0 as min, 5 as max from dual
    union all
    select 'bar' as name, 10 as min, 20 as max from dual
)
connect by prior name = name and level <= max and prior sys_guid() is not null;
```

Comment: @thomsmith - I see from your profile that you may be a C# developer and may not need to or care to go into the subtleties/oddities of Oracle SQL. If so, just use the `... and prior sys_guid() is not null` trick (without the `nocycle`) and don't worry about how or why it works and why it is needed; just know that it is widely used and it does exactly what you were trying to do.